# How do you skip the intermission section instantly in duck game?

Tags: duck-game

When playing online I know it's possible to force the game to begin in the lobby by holding F1 and pressing A.

However I've been in multiple games where the host has immediately skipped the 'intermission' part where the ducks throw a rock to indicate their score.

I'd like to know how they're doing this because when someone refuses to press 'start' to skip it the whole sequence is very tedious.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just a case where all the players happened to hit the skip button right away?

Comment: Yup certain. They can do it almost as soon as the screen loads the playing field

Comment: "it's possible to force the game to begin in the lobby by holding F1 and pressing A." — is this possible by using a controller (I mainly want to update the question)?